# Formatting Excel file to display currency code and amount in the same cell using 'react-data-export' npm package

Tags: excel, reactjs, npm

I am using 'react-data-export' npm package for download excel data from the server. There is a requirement for me to put currency code and amount in the same cell. when we do calculations on the cell, it should work.

I have checked the same thing in the excel, Option is there,

[image]

But, I need to know how it can be done via coding using this npm package.

package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export